# Get values in an XML File - Requirement : It must be done in bash/Unix

Tags: bash, xml

Here is an extract of my XML file :

```
<Value ProtectInMemory="True"> ytznnyg</Value><Value>arulmdbqtza01 </Value><Value>arulmrms </Value><Value>sys/system</Value>
<Value ProtectInMemory="True">kylfpo8</Value><Value>arulmdbqtza02 </Value><Value>arulmrib </Value><Value>sys/system </Value>
<Value ProtectInMemory="True" /><Value>arulmdbsoaa01 </Value><Value>arulmsoa</Value><Value />
<Value ProtectInMemory="True" /><Value>arulmdbsoaa01 </Value><Value>srulmsoa</Value><Value />
```

What I want for the moment :

```
ytznnyg;arulmdbqtza01;arulmrms;sys/system
kylfpo8;arulmdbqtza02;arulmrib;sys/system
;arulmdbsoaa01;arulmsoa;
;arulmdbsoaa01;srulmsoa;
```

What would be great is have the values I separated by semicolons in 4 different variables

What would be amazing is having an output like this:

```
connect sys/ytznnyg@arulmdbqtza01:1521/arulmrms as sysdba @coucou.sql
disconnect
connect system/ytznnyg@arulmdbqtza01:1521/arulmrms @coucou.sql
disconnect
connect sys/kylfpo8@arulmdbqtza02:1521/arulmrib as sysdba @coucou.sql
disconnect
connect system/kylfpo8@arulmdbqtza01:1521/arulmrib @coucou.sql
disconnect
connect /@arulmdbsoaa01:1521/arulmsoa as sysdba @coucou.sql
disconnect
connect /@arulmdbsoaa01:1521/arulmsoa @coucou.sql
disconnect
connect /@arulmdbsoaa01:1521/srulmsoa as sysdba @coucou.sql
disconnect
connect /@arulmdbsoaa01:1521/srulmsoa @coucou.sql
disconnect
```

Comment: Use xslt for extracting the data

Comment: Thank your for your answer. Unfortunately, I can't. I was asked to do it in bash. (I edited my title)

Comment: That is not valid XML - there's an unescaped `<` character in there (or rather, I expect, a missing `>` instead of a space character).

Comment: Closed at OP request

Answer (score 1):

`bash` is a shell, a tool to interpret command lines and run commands. You'll need to call a command or another to do that job. Here using `xmlstarlet` to do the XSLT processing:

```
sed '1s|^|<x>|;$s|$|</x>|' < your-file.xml |
  xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//Value' |
  tr -d ' ' |
  paste -sd ';;;\n' -
```

The above is `bash` code (actually, it's Bourne or POSIX shell code, so it can be interpreted in all Bourne-like shells, not only `bash`) that runs 4 commands in parallel to perform the job. Of those, `sed`, `tr` and `paste` are standard POSIX commands, so would be found on most Unices. `xmlstarlet` you may have to install.

Comment: Nice job, but it doesn't produce the output OP wanted.

Comment: @l0b0. It does for me. What does is do for you?

Comment: The first line is `ytznnygarulmdbqtza01;arulmrms;sys/system;kylfpo8`, which is already off. Tested in `bash` and `sh` with the same result.

Comment: Does it really run in parallel? I thought piping is sequential, no?

Comment: @l0b0, you must have the wrong input file. There's no way it can merge the first two values like that.

Comment: @gt6989b. Of course they run in parallel. How would it work otherwise? pipes are pipes, not giant buckets. The sequentiality is in that the left process has to start writing something to the pipe for the right one to be able to read it and start working on it (if it pleases).

Comment: @StephaneChazelas right, in that sense. Agree.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas I just copied OP's input as it is in the current revision, and got the same, wrong, result.